# D3 html table with row groups from flat array

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, html-table

I'm new to D3 but it seems popular so I thought I'd have a play with html tables and data instead of just doing something dynamic with jquery. Might even do some charts if I get into it. However I'm just wondering if I'm doing things the best or most efficient way. I have the results from a query in an array (not a json structure) e.g.

```
Make     Model     Cost     Year
Ferrari  360       1500     2000
Ferrari  430       2300     2004
Aston    DB9       500      2002
Aston    DB8       750      2010
Porsche  911       850      2007
```

Now I've got things going with a flat html table ok, but if I try to get things going with a rowspan then things start going wrong. At first I thought that I needed to get the data into a hierarchical JSON structure as most of the D3 examples seem to go down that route, but I'm not sure. So for example I might want to have a row grouped html table like this...

```
                   Model     Cost
Make     Ferrari   360       1500
                   430       2300
         Aston     DB9       500
                   DB8       750
```

But I'd want to dynamically have different row groups and columns, even multiple levels of row groups and/or column groups. My question is what is the best and most efficient way of doing this using D3, or am I using a sledgehammer to crack a nut? Do I need to transform the data first or what?